# Can you subclass a generics class with a specific typed class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, subclass

I have a generics class with a subclass that provides specific types.

```
public abstract class GenericBase<T>
    where T:Interface1
{
}
```

I subclass the generics with specific implementations:

```
public class Customer:
    GenericBase<Type1>
```

(`Type1` implements `Interface1`).

I have another abstract base class that has a reference to this:

```
protected GenericBase<Interface1> genericInstance;
```

Finally, when I attempt to assign the genericInstance to an instance of the base class, it gives me a compiler error, saying that it "cannot implicitly convert Customer to GenericBase<Interface1>".

```
base.genericInstance = new Customer(); //Compiler error
```

I don't understand why I would get this error if `Customer` is a subtype of `GenericBase<Type1>`, and `Type1` implements `Interface1`. Isn't `Customer` effectively a type of `GenericBase<Interface1>`, if it's a subclass of `GenericBase<Type1>`?

I assume I'm misunderstanding something about generics here; is there a way to allow this behavior?

Comment: Not sure about in C#, but this definitely doesn't work in Java.  In Java, `genericInstance` would have to be declared as `protected GenericBase<? extends Interface1> genericInstance` (note: I haven't tried it to see if it actually works).

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183)

Comment: The rule of thumb is that generics aren't covariant because you can't tell what will be done with it.  I can't assign a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>` because otherwise, I'd be able to add a `Dog` to the `List<Animal>` despite it really being a `List<Cat>`

Comment: Incidentally, both Java and C# discourage the use of object arrays because arrays *are* covariant... I can assign a `Cat[]` to an `Animal[]` then add a `Dog` to it and the compiler is OK with it.  However, it bombs at runtime.

Comment: Depends on the context, but I'd say at first glance if Customer needs Type1 over Interface1, either Interface1 isn't doing its job sufficiently, or Customer is too smart. Working around this instead of refactoring would be coupling 2 separate layers of abstraction together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C#, covariance (assigning a derived type to a base type) cannot be applied to generic classes.  As a result, you would need to apply an interface specifically marked as covariant, using the [out parameter modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) on a new `IGenericBase` interface.

```
protected IGenericBase<Interface1> genericInstance = new Customer();

public interface IGenericBase<out T> {}

public abstract class GenericBase<T> : IGenericBase<T>
    where T:Interface1 {}

public interface Interface1 {}

public class Type1 : Interface1 {}

public class Customer: GenericBase<Type1> {}
```

Comment: I knew C# had operators similar to Java's weird `<? extends T>` and `<? super T>` syntax, I just didn't know they were `<in T>` and `<out T>`.

Comment: I wasn't able to use a covariant interface because my types were being used both as return values and input parameters in my interface. But at least now I understand a bit about covariance; something I hadn't dealt with before.

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't have covariance of generic classes, which basically means you cannot assign a value with a more derived type argument to a variable with a less derived type argument.

That would work with interfaces, though, provided some conditions are satisfied, namely, if the parameter-type is used in covariant positions only, i.e. as a return type of methods and properties.

Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) and other bits of documentation for more info.