# Extending a generics class with nested generics

Tags: oop, typescript, generics, nested-generics

is there a way in typescript to extend a class in this way:

```
class ChildClass<Wrapper<A>> extends SuperClass<A>
```

This doesn't work but the idea would be to wrap the generics type into a known construct. Here are the docs:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md

This sounds a bit similar to this issue:

[Can you subclass a generics class with a specific typed class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748661/can-you-subclass-a-generics-class-with-a-specific-typed-class)

I don't do much oop so I'm not very familiar with stuff like covariance and contravariance, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It maeks no sense to write `ChildClass<Wrapper<A>>` before the extends, because there you *declare* the generic type parameters. That means you can give them a name and, if you need to, a constraint (for example `ChildClass<A extends Wrapper>`). What does `Wrapper<A>` mean in this context? The compiler can make no sense of it.

What is absolutely possible is to use `Wrapper<A>` on *the other side of the extends*, because there `A` is not a (formal) type *parameter*, but a type *argument*. That means you are *using* the type parameter previously defined and there you can generate new types with it.

So depending on what you actually *want to do*, there are two options for you:

**`A` is assignable to `Wrapper`**

When you want to make sure the `A` is a `Wrapper` or a derived class, use a generic constraint:

```
class ChildClass<A extends Wrapper> extends SuperClass<A>
```

**`A` is a type argument of `Wrapper<>`**

If `Wrapper<>` is itself a generic class or interface and you want to use `A` as its type argument, do this:

```
class ChildClass<A> extends SuperClass<Wrapper<A>>
```

Comment: Yes the `Wrapper` is a generic class itself and `A` its argument... I was trying the wrong way around but now that I see it like this, it somehow actually makes sense

Comment: `class ChildClass<A implements Wrapper> extends SuperClass<A>{}` is not valid TypeScript.  A generic type parameter only `extends` a type (even if that type is an interface), it never `implements` it.  So `class ChildClass<A extends Wrapper> extends SuperClass<A>{}` is the only appropriate way to express the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) that `A` is assignable to `Wrapper`.

Comment: @jcalz I have removed that part from my answer.